# DOMException: Failed to execute 'removeChild' on 'Node'. When render with a map a component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am having a problem, because I have a Map, which what it does is it takes values ​​from a Tree and passes it to the component. This component is a category slider, with products.

So when the service responds very fast, it doesn't finish rendering the component the first time and start the other one, how could I handle it?

```
const getProductsWithTree = () => {
if(ifExistAndMayorToZero(tree)) {
  return (
    tree.map((category:any) => {
      return (
        <GlobalComponents.ProductSliderAsync
          filterBrand={false}
          singleProviderId={vendorId}
          category={category}
          hideMore={true}
          isLoading={isLoadingProducts}
          brandId={brandId}
          validateIfIsHasProducts={ifIsHasProducts}
          {...props}
        />
      )
    })
  )
}
}
```

I came up with something, like knowing when I will return to handle the map, but I don't know.

This does not work and the error occurs, when it responds very fast, if I put the slow connection, it works there without problem.

Answer (score 0):

In case "the service" refers to the source of the tree, you could store the tree in state to cause re-render of the slider when the tree changes.

In case it refers to an external service that is causing another component to render over the slider before it completes rendering with the tree, you could hold off on rendering the said second component ("the other one") until after the slider has completed rendering.

A simplistic conceptualization of the second case:

If one component impacts rendering of another, presumably they share a conditional logic.

Perhaps you can refine the conditional by letting ProductSlider update a value in store (let's call it `sliderRenderIsDone`) and add it to the shared conditional:

```
{ treeIsReady
    ? sliderRenderIsDone ? OtherComponent : ProductSlider
    : null 
}
```

Comment: Could you give me an example of the second option? :)